# [Solved]Problem with rosmake and rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node

Tags: ros-groovy, camera, usb-cam-node, rosrun, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good afternoon partners

Following the tutorial for installing usb_cam on groovy

> http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi#ROS_Peripherals

I can roscd usb_cam and I have all the dependencies installed but when I do the rosmake I'm given the next :

```
 Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! -------------------------------------------------------------------------------} 
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package usb_cam written to: 
[ rosmake ] /home/pi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140116-192405/usb_cam/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< usb_cam [FAIL] [ 16.84 seconds ] 
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package usb_cam.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete. 
[ rosmake ] Results: 
[ rosmake ] Built 36 packages with 1 failures. 
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory 
[ rosmake ] /home/pi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140116-192405
```

And if I try rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node I'm given :

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named usb_cam_node below /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/bosch_drivers/usb_cam
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files
[rosrun] or not executable: 
[rosrun] /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/bosch_drivers/usb_cam/src/usb_cam_node
```

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the output_build log:

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -
DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
[rosbuild] Building package usb_cam
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests usb_cam [rospack] Error: package/stack 'usb_cam' depends on non-existent package 'self_test' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'usb_cam'. Look above for errors from rospack itself. Aborting. Please fix the broken dependency!
Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack) CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_init)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make: * [all] Error 1
```

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118736/%5Bsolved%5Dproblem-with-rosmake-and-rosrun-usb_cam-usb_cam_node/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-16**:
It sounds like the usb_cam package is failing to build. Can you post the rest of the rosmake output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the build log, you're missing the `self_test` package which is a dependency:

```
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests usb_cam [rospack] Error: package/stack 'usb_cam' depends on non-existent package 'self_test' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
```

According to the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/self_test), the `self_test` package is part of the `diagnostics` stack. I suggest you add the entire diagnostics stack to your catkin workspace, and rebuild your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-01-16**:
Ok. It's in progress. I'm telling you when it finished. Thanks.

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-01-16**:
Ok. I've just added the entire diagnostics stack in my catkin_ws and rebuilded it. Now when I invoke rosmake usb_cam everything finish OK.
I've just run "rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node" and it worked for me. Know I have to fin my webcam .
Thanks you so much.